What should be our policy on spoiler formatting, and on editing it into/out of posts?
This post is inspired by a recent edit war in which an answer which contained the phrase "spoiler alert" but did not contain any actual spoiler formatting (using the >! syntax) repeatedly had spoiler formatting edited in and out of it. In comments, two people mentioned that spoiler formatting is inaccessible to keyboard-only users as a justification for removing it from posts altogether, but I don't think Lit SE has any clear policy concerning this.
Relevant previous meta posts:

Should we assume that questions about a book spoil that book, or should we use spoiler markup? (highly voted but from 2017's private beta period): top answer says "If the OP is asking for advice about a book they have not read, answers should be considerate of this and consider putting major plot points in spoiler markup."
Is it acceptable to remove spoiler blockquotes from questions and answers? (also from 2017's private beta period): top answer says it's OK to remove spoiler formatting from answers if it's excessive or being used for non-spoilerific content, but not otherwise.
Spoiler feature (from 2021): question is somewhat unclear what it's asking, top answer (+9/-3) says to discourage spoiler formatting and second answer (+4/-0) cites "current consensus" (although I can't find a source for the last part of this) that "make a reasonable effort in order not to spoil things in question body, but when it comes to answers all bets are off".

Do we want to change the consensus from 2017 that answers should consider putting major plot points in spoiler markup? Furthermore, what kind of editing is acceptable to support whatever consensus we arrive at: is it OK to edit spoiler markup into someone else's answer if they didn't include it originally, and conversely, is it OK to edit it out of someone else's answer if they did include it?
Please avoid discussion of whether the particular answer linked at the start of this meta post is actually spoilery or not. The answerer acknowledged in comments that it might not be, but this meta is an attempt to build a general consensus.

Can blind people access spoiler which are marked up, or not? I think this should make a difference in our decision.

@PeterShor It's not just about blind people. Sighted keyboard users can't access the spoilers at all, and there are more sighted keyboard users than blind people.

But are there many sighted keyboard users who don't have some kind of access to technology that would let them access the spoilers?

@PeterShor Are you asking whether it is fine to discriminate against people if it's only a small group? Even though the problem should be easy to fix?

@Tsundoku: I'm asking whether the people that we're discriminating against are just moderately inconvenienced, or are completely unable to see the spoilers. In the building where I work, there are some entrances that are inaccessible for wheelchairs, but others that are wheelchair-accessible. So people in wheelchairs approaching from some directions currently have to travel significantly longer to get in. Should we close the wheelchair-inaccessible entrances so as to put everybody on the same footing?

Disabled people can hit the "edit" button to read the markdown source. That lets them read the spoilers. It's a bad option, but it's much better than the options available to disabled (or non-disabled) people who want to unread a spoiler. (And yes, it works for people who aren't logged in.)

It's worth noting that spoilers can be accessed with some tools. For example, VoiceOver on iOS makes it easy to press the "reveal spoiler" thing. The only issues are that 1) the spoilered text appears before that part of the page, so you have to backtrack unintuitively if you want it to be read to you and 2) the text "reveal spoiler" is only visually removed, but can still be read out or show the focus indicator, which makes it hard to read the actual text.

We should avoid spoiler markup when discussing the work named in the question.
The accessibility consideration has been well covered by Tsundoku's answer, so I won't repeat that here. But even if one is not using a screen reader or other assistive technology, the use of spoiler markup is disruptive to the reading experience by hiding the text from view until clicked on. Additionally, until clicked on, the text renders incorrectly in “Reader view” in Safari, and is not copied by the “Copy” function. No doubt there are other features which don’t work properly, but these are the ones I’ve noticed.
It's reasonable to expect people not to read questions and answers on works for which they are concerned about being spoiled. The name of the work appears in a tag, and very often also in the question title, so that it is easy to skip questions for which one prefers not to know the answer.
Additionally, at Literature Stack Exchange I would hope that we all believe that there is more to a literary work than the resolution of the plot, so that accidentally learning (say) that Hamlet dies, or Oedipus married his mother, is not going to spoil these plays.
In summary:

It’s fair to assume that a question or answer about Hamlet or Oedipus may discuss the plot of the play, and similarly for any other work. This is the whole point of the site!

It’s reasonable to remove spoiler markup from questions and answers, for accessibility, or just to make the post easier to read.


There may be a case for spoiler markup where works not mentioned in the question are spoiled in an answer, but even in these cases the markup should be used as sparingly as possible. I think that a justifiable case is this answer of mine, in which, in the midst of a general discussion of Agatha Christie’s body of work, I back up a couple of my points by naming the murderer or the method of murder for many of the author’s mysteries. Note that the answer can still be read, and still makes sense, without the marked-up paragraphs.

"But even if one is not using a screen reader or other assistive technology, the use of spoiler markup is disruptive to the reading experience by hiding the text from view until clicked on." - that's a minor inconvenience at most. It's far lower than the impact an unwanted spoiler can have.

"The name of the work appears in a tag" - tags aren't visible from the HNQ list. That list just shows titles. A work being named in a question title may be functional as a spoiler warning, but tags aren't enough for people coming from HNQ.

@user2357112 Normally the work is named in the question title; if not, we can edit the question to add it; if no-one edits the title, then people coming via HNQ can read the question at that point and so discover the name of the work and then decide whether to proceed to the answers at that point.

If the question is short enough that the answers are already visible on page load, that doesn't work. People can't decide not to see what's on the bottom half of their screen.

@user2357112 Perhaps it would help if you listed the last five or ten questions which went to HNQ, which did not name the work in the title, and where the work was spoiled in any of the answers. Then we could see how much of a problem this is in practice.

I don't know how to search for questions that made it to HNQ, besides a tedious manual search. This question would be problematic, but it didn't hit HNQ. I suspect story identification questions would often be problematic, since the entire idea is that the asker doesn't know what story it is. This question, for example, which did hit HNQ.

It looks like spoilers mostly go unmarked in identification requests, for both questions and answers. That's not great for people who don't like spoilers but would like to help identify stories - they mostly can't risk opening that entire category of questions. The potential density of spoiler tags needed to do anything about that could get very tedious, though.

@user2357112 You can find questions that went HNQ by searching for "Literature" in the "Hot Network Questions" chat room.

@user2357112 I don't find the Juan Rulfo example convincing. Rulfo is not a writer whose stories depend on suspense about the plot, so there is nothing to be spoiled. If someone finds that learning anything about a work of literature spoils it for them, then I think the onus is really on them to stay clear of the site.

This question includes spoilers for the movie Encanto, but doesn't include the name of the movie in either the title or the tags, and people aren't going to expect movie spoilers on the literature site.

@user2357112 In the Encanto case, editing the name of the film into the title of the question would be better (and much easier!) than re-writing the question so that the plot details are concealed. (Also, it's hard to imagine anyone would really be spoiled by learning that the theme of a Disney movie is that family is important.)

Editing the name in would indeed be a better option there. And I don't know anything about Rulfo, so I can't contest your argument on Rulfo's works.

@user2357112 I have edited the Encanto question, it didn't take long.

@user2357112 In the "Death of Doctor Island" case, it is hard to see how to address the spoiler problem by adding markup. Even if the entire answer was marked up as a spoiler, it would not help, because in order to know whether it would be safe to reveal the answer, you would have to know the name of the story, which would already spoil it for you.

I'm not really sure if there's a good answer for story identification either.

Taking a step back, my primary experience with spoiler discussion is from video games, where the answer to "how do I get past this door" might be "come back after you fight your evil dad", and it's reasonable to ask or look up the door question without wanting to see the evil dad spoiler. The closest analogue for literature would be someone trying to clarify something they're confused about midway through a book, so they'll understand the rest of it. In that case, clarification based on later story events would be spoilery.

I don't know how common that kind of question actually is around here, or how often answers involve spoilers. I think I would need an amount of work-specific knowledge I don't have to determine whether questions are the kind of thing someone might want to ask before they finish the work.

@user2357112 Literature and games are very different in this respect. Games are constructed around puzzles or challenges that many people want the pleasure of solving or completing for themselves. But almost no literature is constructed in this way—perhaps only a handful of "fair play" mystery stories from the early-to-mid C20. With literature, what people are concerned about spoiling is the pleasure of suspense, that is, reading a story while not knowing how it turns out. But in most works suspense is one component among many, and you can enjoy a work while knowing the plot.

@user2357112 There is also pleasure in what we do here at Literature Stack Exchange, which includes discussion of the plots and outcomes of stories. For this reason, although we might take care not to reveal too much about the plot of works where suspense is a major component, I think the balance is best if people who read the site accept the risk of learning things about literature!

@GarethRees: I want to disagree about "almost no literature is constructed that way" — I'd say many, if not most, mystery novels still are. If you ask what appears to be an innocent question, and the answer gives away who the murderer is, we definitely want to mark that as a spoiler.

To add to my previous comment, I've read a handful of books that are mystery/thrillers, where the protagonist figures out who the murderer is maybe three quarters of the way through, and then the book turns into a thriller with the protagonist trying to avoid being killed. (Lewis Shiner's Black and White was one such book, and a very good one.) When I run into one of these books, I'm always a little bit disappointed that I didn't get a chance to sit down for an hour and  try to figure out who the murderer was — not that I succeed in solving most murder mysteries, but it's fun to try.


Use spoiler markup.

Broadly, no.

The question is indeed, unclear.


I don't really understand what the problem is here. Spoiler formatting is non-obvious but that's a reason to for posters not to bother with hiding spoilers in the first place, and absolutely not a reason to resist or re-edit questions where someone else has thoughtfully put the spoilers in.
There are, of course, context-dependent exceptions, mainly around readability, but for me the general rule should be that spoilers should be hidden.

"1. Use spoiler markup." Your answer is incomplete without an explanation of why you think it's fine to discriminate against people with disabilities, because that is what spoiler markup currently does.

I think that saying that spoiler markup "discriminates against people with disabilities" is excessive. It makes it sound as if there is an active campaign against people with disabilities. I don't think that adding spoiler markup to answers should be classed as being just as bad as overt racism or sexism, which would also be called "discrimination". I think it would be more accurate to say that it makes it harder for people with disabilities to interact with the site, which I agree may be a problem.

@ZerGreenOne - It may not be an active decision to discriminate, but the end result is that it does interfere with some people's ability to use the site, and viewing that as a non-issue can be viewed as ableist. Ableism is an issue much like racism and sexism are, and in this case it not only creates an oppressive environment but actively makes viewing content on the site impossible for certain users.

The accessibility argument seems to be based on the idea that automatically seeing spoilers produces a preferable outcome for disabled people over an unreadable section of the post. But this is only true for a subset of disabled people.
For many people, seeing a spoiler can ruin their enjoyment of a work. This is true for both disabled and non-disabled people. Automatically seeing spoilers is much worse for these people than a spoiler block they can't open.
This is how various people are affected by using or not using spoiler tags:




Disabled people
Non-disabled people




Like spoilers
Hurt by spoiler tags
Unaffected either way


Don't like spoilers
Hurt by removing spoiler tags
Hurt by removing spoiler tags



Spoiler tags cause poor outcomes for people in the upper left box, but removing spoiler tags causes poor outcomes for people in the entire bottom row. This is a larger group of people than the group hurt by spoiler tags, and includes a similar number of disabled people.
Additionally, avoiding spoiler markup has the following problems:

If Stack Exchange updates to an accessible implementation of spoiler markup, all posts that use spoiler markup instantly become accessible.
On the other hand, if we avoid spoiler markup, then we're left with thousands of posts with unmarked spoilers still spoiling things for everyone who reads them unless someone manually goes through a giant backlog, checking for spoilers (and getting spoiled) and adding the markup.

If people want to read a spoiler they're prevented from reading, they can find the information elsewhere. If people want to unread a spoiler they were shown unexpectedly, they're out of luck.


Spoiler markup may have a more obvious impact on accessibility, but the alternative hurts a larger group of people (including a similar number of people with disabilities) in a way that cannot be easily rectified.
For these reasons, I support the use of spoiler markup, and do not consider it a worse option for accessibility, despite its flaws.

"the idea that reading spoilers is what people with disabilities want": that is a misrepresentation of the argument. The argument is that people with disabilities have the same right to spoilers as everybody else. The current implementation does not give them that right and is therefore discriminatory.

@Tsundoku: They also have the same right to not see spoilers. Your proposed alternative would take that right away from disabled and non-disabled people alike.

Removing spoiler markup doesn't make things better for disabled people in general. It makes things better for a specific subgroup of disabled people who like spoilers, while making things worse for disabled people who don't like spoilers, and also making things worse for non-disabled people who don't like spoilers. That's not an improvement.

"They also have the same right to not see spoilers." It's only a spoiler widget if you can actually reveal the spoiler. Mouse users are given the choice to reveal the spoiler or not, whereas keyboard-only users are excluded from that choice. You are advocating discrimination against people with disabilities.

"Removing spoiler markup doesn't make things better for disabled people in general." Removing spoiler markup puts everyone on an equal footing. Keeping it discriminates.

@Tsundoku: A bad equal footing isn't an improvement. Imagine if spoiler markup had the opposite accessibility problem - imagine if disabled people automatically saw spoilers. Would you still be trying to put everyone on an equal footing? Would you advocate for removing spoiler markup in this situation, even though it would only hurt non-disabled people and provide no benefit for disabled people? Or would you advocate for removing the underlying spoilers themselves, making them accessible to nobody?

"Imagine if spoiler markup had the opposite accessibility problem" That is not the problem we are dealing with. Spoilers don't hurt anyone anyway. You just continue advocating discrimination against people with disabilities.

@Tsundoku: For many people, a spoiler can ruin their enjoyment of a work. This is what your proposal would do to a large segment of the disabled population. Doing this to disabled people doesn't become a good thing just because you'd be doing it to non-disabled people too. You're not actually improving outcomes for disabled people.
